# Use Lollipop transitions with Holo themes

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the new Lollipop transition animations in my app for devices that have Lollipop installed but I can't seem to get it working.

Notes about the current situation: I haven't changed the theme for my app. It's still using the Holo themes with the action bars and everything else. I'll eventually change them to use toolbars and everything else "material design" but reading the documentations here https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions I was under the impression that it was possible to enable transitions programmatically and without having to change themes.

Here's what I've done so far (which is not working):

On every activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        initializeAnimations();
    }

    setContentView(...)
}
```

And the method:

```
private void initializeAnimations() {
    Transition ts = new Explode();

    ts.setStartDelay(2000);
    ts.setDuration(5000);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
    getWindow().setEnterTransition(ts);
    getWindow().setExitTransition(ts);
    getWindow().setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(true);
    getWindow().setSharedElementEnterTransition(ts);
    getWindow().setSharedElementExitTransition(ts);
}
```

And I also start my activities as follows:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    startActivity(intent, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle());
    return;
}
```

As per the documentation.

The behavior I'm seeing however is that no animation is ever applied. I even tried settings up a `SharedElementCallback` to see if it gets called by setting:

```
setEnterSharedElementCallback(new SharedElementCallback (...) );
```

But methods such as `onSharedElementStart()` are never called.

So my question is: Is it possible to setup transition animations in code, without changing the theme and if so, how do I go about doing that? What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance,